# Stuck with Augensterm in Metal Slug 5

Tags: metal-slug-5

I had eliminated all enemies, until I found the end of the subway rails. After that I couldn't proceed, and I wasn't getting the typical mandatory "ok-that's-enough-step-out-of-the-slug-now" instruction you get when you reach a place where your vehicle can't go.

I was stuck, any way to proceed with [Augensterm](https://metalslug.fandom.com/wiki/Slugs)?

[image]

PS: I think I was also unable to exit the Augensterm, let alone proceeding with it...